# Selenium locator for element for combining ID which one part is static and one is dynamic

Tags: selenium

Selenium locator for element for combining ID which one part is static and one is dynamic.

I have one ID which combined with two parts i.e. xyz_abc , where xyz is static and abc is changing ,

How can i make xpath or any locator for selenium?

Comment: Relevant HTML and code trials please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have provided some more details such as html layout, language - Java/Python/Javascript and what you have tried before asking

Anyway

in Java

String variable = "abc"; // which would change

String locator = "xyz_" + variable

Answer (score 1):

suppose "id=edit_1545" here edit is static,numbers are dynamic then in that case we can use xpath as `//*[contains(@id,'edit')]` OR `//*[starts_with(@id,'edit')]`